# Is there a bible contradiction between 1 Kings 8:26 and 2 Chronicles 22:2?

Tags: contradiction, 2-kings, 2-chronicles

How can we as Christians explain the supposed bible contradiction between both 2 Kings 8:26 and 2 Chronicles 22:2, where they both give an entirely different age for the reign  of Ahaziah, would this be considered a bible contradiction?

> Two and twenty years old was Ahaziah when he began to reign; and he
> reigned one year in Jerusalem. And his mother's name was Athaliah, the
> daughter of Omri king of Israel - **2 Kings 8:26**

**2 Kings 8:26**

> Forty and two years old was Ahaziah when he began to reign, and he
> reigned one year in Jerusalem. His mother's name also was Athaliah the
> daughter of Omri - **2 Chronicles 22:2**

Comment: Please search for duplicate questions, thanks!

Comment: All of these so-called 'contradictions' have been extensively dealt with elsewhere and also in the archives of this site. Just Googling and searching our archives first will usually give a rapid answer. Genuine cases of apparent ambiguity are often a matter of translation or of an incomplete knowledge of the extent of scripture.